# How to create a new tab in a Microsoft Access form

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am learning about Microsoft Access and need to create a user menu to access other forms. I know how to make buttons/controls to open the needed form, but I cannot get it to open in a new tab[image]

How do I get "frmType" to open in a tab next to menu? I have been making the menu form using a tab control if that makes any difference.

Comment: And I don't know VBA or much SQL, I am building this using the macro builder

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Tab control. New database is set to Tabbed Documents mode by default. Objects will open as tabbed documents. This is what the lesson is demonstrating. The tab illustrated is a Tabbed Document, not a page tab of a Tab control.